# Convert the Future<List<String>> to List<String> when calls the Sqflite function

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I want to get all the items from the database, but i am stuck how to convert the Future list of strings to list of strings.

```
var x =  DataBaseHelper.instance.queryAllRows();


 Future<List<String>> queryAllRows() async {
    Database db = await instance._initDatabase();
    List<Map<String,dynamic>> s =  await db.query(table ,columns: [columnname]);
    List<String> list = new List();
    for(var x in s){
      x.forEach((k,v)=>list.add(v));
    }
    return list;
 }
```

I want to get all the values in the database but dont know how to convert those values to the List

Comment: To get from your `List<Map<String,dynamic>>` to a `List<String>` with all the values in all the maps you could do: `var list = List<String>.from(s.expand((m) => m.values))`

Comment: Please see my post at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63082129/7681696

Comment: @NateBosch I followed your suggestion but getting an error "The argument type 'Future<List<dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<dynamic>'". Thank you.

Comment: @Kamlesh my comment is about the handling the types _other_ than the asynchronous bit. See the answers below for information about handling a `Future`. See also https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an asynchronous function to retrieve the data.

```
void yourFunction() async {
     var x =  await DataBaseHelper.instance.queryAllRows();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two of choices. You can use future builder to create widgets or use plain futures + `setState`

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

```
List<String> _databaseList

queryAllRows().then((rows) {

   setState(() {_databaseList = rows});
})
```

`setState` will tell the flutter to rebuild the widget tree. `then` to process the future.

Answer (score 1):

Because db.querys are asynchronous, they are going to return a `Future<List<Map<String,dynamic>>`. To get their result without a future, we can get a call back and it will return a `List<Map<String,dynamic>>` instead.

```
var x =  DataBaseHelper.instance.queryAllRows();

  Future<List<String>> queryAllRows() async {
    Database db = await instance._initDatabase();
    db.query(table ,columns: [columnname]).then((data){
      List<Map<String,dynamic>> s = data;
      List<String> list = new List();
      for(var x in s){
        x.forEach((k,v)=>list.add(v));
      }
    });
    return list;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry dear, this solution did not work for me and was resulting me an error "Instance of 'Future<List<dynamic>>'" in debug console. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to await the queryAllRows() to complete. If you are in the context of a function that can be marked as async just need to use the keyword :

```
void someFunction() async {
var x =  await DataBaseHelper.instance.queryAllRows(); // x is List<String>
}
```

Instead, if you want to render the list you can use the FutureBuilder and manage the render widget based on Future state :

```
Widget test(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
    future: DataBaseHelper.instance.queryAllRows(),
    builder: (context, snap) {
      if (snap.hasData && !snap.hasError) {
        return ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          children: <Widget>[...snap.data],
        );
      }
      else {
        return Container();
      }
    },
  );
}
```