# How to convert Future<List> to List in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, future, flutter-dependencies

I am using a plugin for flutter called `search_widget`.
The data parameter of this widget takes a list. But as I use `sqlite` for fetching data, I have it in `Future<List>` form.
Is there any way I can convert `Future<List>` to `List`?
Or any other way to get this working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Borrowing the example from [search_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/search_widget) you need `dataList` in a widget like this:

```dart
SearchWidget<LeaderBoard>(
   dataList: list,
   textFieldBuilder: (TextEditingController controller, FocusNode focusNode) {
     return MyTextField(controller, focusNode);
   },
 )
```

Sure, you can convert `Future<List>` into `List` like other answers suggest. But you **won't** be able to do `dataList: await _sqliteCall();` because `build` methods are designed to be pure and sychronous.

While the Future completes you will have to return something like a progress indicator. For that you can use a `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
FutureBuilder<List<Leaderboard>>(
  future: _sqliteCall(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return SearchWidget<LeaderBoard>(
        dataList: snapshot.data,
        textFieldBuilder: (TextEditingController controller, FocusNode focusNode) {
          return MyTextField(controller, focusNode);
        },
      )
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
),
```

Of course this can also be done with a `StatefulWidget`, you can check [this article for a detailed explanation of the issue](https://flutterigniter.com/build-widget-with-async-method-call/).

Answer (score 22):

Using `await` keyword will wait for Future to get completed and once your Future is executed it's result will be returned to you.

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
  Future<List> _futureOfList = _getList();
  List list = await _futureOfList ;
  print(list); // will print [1, 2, 3, 4] on console.
}

Future<List>  _getList(){
  return Future.value([1,2,3,4]);
}
```

for this to work, the method where you are calling should be `async`

I hope this helps, in case of any doubt please comment.

Answer (score 16):

```
List list = await _fetchList();
```

Assuming `_fetchList()` is something like:

```
Future<List> _fetchList() {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats how I have solved the problem...

Initial version:

```
  @override
  List<Product> getAll() {
    List<Product> _listProducts;
    Future<List<Product>> listFuture;
    listFuture = _repo.getAll();
    listFuture.then((value) {
      if (value != null) value.forEach((item) => _listProducts.add(item));
    });
    return _listProducts == null ? [] : _listProducts;
  }
```

Cleaned up/final version:

```
  @override
  List<Product> getAll() {
    List<Product> _listProducts;
    _repo.getAll().then((value) {
      if (value != null) value.forEach((item) => _listProducts.add(item));
    });
    return _listProducts == null ? [] : _listProducts;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming this is ur returning function dataList() which is Futur :

```
 List yourlist = new List();
   dataList().then((resultat){
          setState(() => yourlist.add(resultat); 
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 List listItems = [];
        
          getList() async {
          listItems = await Future<List> listofFuture;
          }

    ...   
    
    ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
          setState(() {});},
          child: Text('Update Data'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<Future<dynamic>> _selectedItems = List<Future<dynamic>>();
    List<dynamic> listofimg = [];
                                    _selectedItems.forEach((element) {
                                      element.then((value) => listofimg.add(value));
                                    });
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64980911/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

> future return of apiservice type (Future list). we use key word (then) then future type store to var result as list.

You should call value on {} of then as below:

```
onPressed: () {
 _apiService.getProductList().then((result) {
    print(result);
    print("kkkkkkkk:"+result.length.toString());
    for   (var item in result){
    _dsSanpham.add(item);

    }
    Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => nhaphangle(
            username: username, dshangle: dshangle, dssanpham: _dsSanpham)),);
});
```