# Flutter error : The argument type 'List<Future<Widget>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I'm trying to do a list of item from Firebase Firestore (this is done) and to get for each item a different image URL from Firebase Cloud Storage.

I use a function called **getPhotoUrl** to change the value of the variable photoUrl. The problem is that the **return** is executed before **getPhotoUrl**. If I add **await** in front of the function **getPhotoUrl** and **async** after **_docs.map((document)**, I got an error saying that *The argument type 'List<Future>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'*.

My code:

```
class PhotosList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PhotosListState createState() => _PhotosListState();
}

class _PhotosListState extends State<PhotosList> {
  String photoUrl = 'lib/assets/default-image.png';
  List<DocumentSnapshot> _docs;

  getPhotoUrl(documentID) {
    Reference ref = storage
        .ref('Users')
        .child(currentUser.uid)
        .child('Photos')
        .child(documentID)
        .child('image_1.jpg');
    ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        photoUrl = value.toString();
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      setState(() {
        print(e.error);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: firestore
          .collection('Users')
          .doc(currentUser.uid)
          .collection('Photos')
          .orderBy('date')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
        _docs = snapshot.data.docs;
        if (_docs.isEmpty)
          return Center(
              child: Text("The list is empty."));
        return Container(
          child: ResponsiveGridList(
            desiredItemWidth: 100,
            squareCells: true,
            minSpacing: 5,
            children: _docs.map((document) {
              getPhotoUrl(document.id);
              return PhotosListItem(photoUrl: photoUrl);
            }).toList(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers guys, actually I found an other solution which is to get and write the URL in Firestore directly after uploading the image on the Storage.

This is the article which helped me a lot : https://medium.com/swlh/uploading-images-to-cloud-storage-using-flutter-130ac41741b2

(PS: some of the Firebase names changed since this article but it's still helpful.)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mix 2 different ways. In every build cicle you map your docs and request that photoUrl, but inside that method you call setState, which re-triggers your build method. That way you should end in infinite loop of getting photo url and building your widget.

You have three options:

1. Load your photoUrls and store them inside your widget -> call set state -> check inside your mapping function if your photo is loaded, if yes, take it, if no, call your getPhotoUrl function
2. Load your photoUrls synchronously and return url from your function and set it to your PhotosListItem
3. (I would prefer this) Add your documentId to your photosListItem in your mapping function and inside your item you load this photo url. In this PhotoListItem you have a variable with your imageUrl and in initState you call your getPhotoUrl function

Inside your PhotoItem:

```
  String imageUrl;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      setState(() {
        // load your data and set it to your variable
        imageUrl = ..
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use a FutureBuilder because StreamBuilder seems to be synchronous :

[How to convert Future<List> to List in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489064/how-to-convert-futurelist-to-list-in-flutter)